# C# - System.StackOverflowException with Lambda

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, sorting, stack-overflow

Under what situations would this code error out with System.StackOverflowException?

```
Accounts.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.AccountId, y.AccountId));
```

**Update**:
the property is written as:

```
    public string AccountId
    {
        get { return _accountId; }
        set { _accountId = value; }
    }
```

Nothing special going on at all. Sort is not overridden either.

Comment: What is the type of Accounts?  `List<string>`?

Comment: Out of interest how many items are in Accounts?

Comment: about 10 objects in Accounts. and the Type of accounts is List<Account>

Comment: Are you certain it's *this* line that throws the `StackOverflowException`?

Comment: Does the Account class override Equals() or define operator ==

Comment: Can you share more of the context around this line, i.e. the method it is in.  See my suggestion below.

Comment: @tyndall: What was it? I'm really curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the callstack and you will see which function is executed over and over again. If this is not possible (because it is running inside a production environment for example), give more info.

about what the called properties call, where this function is called, etc

Answer (score 5):

If `AccountId` does something non-trivial (*anything* except access a local field) then that is the most likely bet.

An interesting fact is that *technically* `Sort` requires the ordering to be transitive, and string comparison is [not always transitive](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/236900/string-compare-not-always-transitive)! But this would rarely cause a stackoverflow (unless the `Sort` method uses some kind of FP approach); it *might* cause it to run forever, but I believe the inbuilt types even have this covered (they check for the theoretical max run-length and abort, IIRC).

I would be looking at `AccountId`; if it does something "clever" (like lazy-load some value from a parent collection), odds are the bug is in the "clever".

Comment: The transitive bug appears to be fixed in .Net 4.0

Answer (score 5):

So I had a tricky situation where I was getting StackOverflow exceptions in a comparison method.

My comparison method:

```
public bool Equals(Type rhs)
{
    if (rhs == null) return false;
    if (this == rhs) return true;

    return this.randomField.Equals(rhs.randomField);
}
```

My operator:

```
public static bool operator ==(Type lhs, Type rhs)
{
    if (lhs == null)
        return (rhs == null);
    else
        return lhs.Equals(rhs);
}
```

So, what had happened was the == operator was calling the Equals method, which was then calling the == operator when it ran the line `this == rhs`. The solution was to convert the line to `Object.ReferenceEquals(this, rhs)`.

Comment: The question edit made it in after I had started writing my post. Obviously there would not be such a problem with strings.

Answer (score 4):

### Here's an off-the-wall idea:

**Is Accounts *declared* as `List<Account>`?**

I'm wondering if `Accounts` is a property declared as something other than `List<Account>` -- for instance, as `IList<Account>` -- and you have a static helper class somewhere with a `Sort` extension method that isn't implemented properly. This could attempt to leverage the `List<T>.Sort` method when the parameter passed in is a `List<T>`, but do so without performing the necessary cast to `List<T>`, resulting in a guaranteed `StackOverflowException`.

What I mean is this. Suppose `Account` is a property of some class that looks something like this:

```
public class AccountManager
{
    public IList<Account> Accounts { get; private set; }

    public AccountManager()
    {
        // here in the constructor, Accounts is SET to a List<Account>;
        // however, code that interacts with the Accounts property will
        // only know that it's interacting with something that implements
        // IList<Account>
        Accounts = new List<Account>();
    }
}
```

And then suppose elsewhere you have this static class with a `Sort` extension method:

```
public static class ListHelper
{
    public static void Sort<T>(this IList<T> list, Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        // programmer tries to use the built-in sort, if possible
        if (list is List<T>)
        {
            // only problem is, list is here still typed as IList<T>,
            // so this line will result in infinite recursion
            list.Sort(comparison);

            // the CORRECT way to have done this would've been:
            // ((List<T>)list).Sort(comparison);

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            list.CustomSort(comparison);
            return;
        }
    }

    private static void CustomSort<T>(this IList<T> list, Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        // some custom implementation
    }
}
```

In this case, the code you posted would throw a `StackOverflowException`.

---

### Original answer:

Perhaps `Accounts` is an object of a custom collection class whose `Sort` method calls itself?

```
public class AccountCollection : IEnumerable<Account> {
    // ...
    public void Sort(Comparison<Account> comparison) {
        Sort(comparison); // infinite recursion
    }
    // ...
}
```

Perhaps the `AccountId` property calls itself?

```
public class Account {
    // ...
    public string AccountId {
        get { return AccountId; } // infinite recursion
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`StackOverflowException`s usually happen when you have a recursive call that goes wild. Check to see if either `Sort` or `AccountId` are calling themselves. If so, check the base-cases for those recursive functions and make sure they're stopping when they're supposed to stop.

Answer (score 2):

Just because THIS line is throwing the StackOverflow doesn't mean that it's the cause of the problem, e.g.

```
void methodA()
{
   b();
   methodA();
}
```

This is as likely to get a stack overflow on b() as it is on the recursive call to methodA();

I suspect the recursion is on the method around this line of code.